# Google drive cannot start up and no log file found

Tags: google-drive-api

Haven't used google drive for a long time. Now just want to sync files between win 7 and google driver. Google driver won't start up after reinstall or start with admin. Local user has admin right. There is no sync_log.log in the driver folder C:\Users*username*\AppData\Local\Google\Drive even with debug flag "--vv". There is no crash report neither. 
Checked folder ownership and permission, all looks good. 
event log has no warning/error.
Out of options and need help.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow after numerous installations and changing ownership of folders to my username, I managed to get an error during installation about python27.dll error code 5. From link https://superuser.com/questions/668820/google-drive-error-python27-dll, I changed the compatibility mode of executable to fit win 7 and it worked.